# Distributed Map configured programmatically, is not visible on the other node in the cluster(checked through Hazelcast cmd prompt)

Tags: hazelcast

I started exploring hazelcast cache. On my laptop, i have 2 instances of hazelcast running.
One from my eclipse, and other from bin/run.bat

I did this from my eclipse sample program.

```
IMap t= Hazelcast.getMap("test");
test.put(3, "three");
```

Now, i went to the hazelcast prompt in the run.bat shell, and tried "test.entries". Its not listing any entries..

Can somebody please let me know What would have gone wrong!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"test.entries" is not right command. All map commands start with 'm.' like 'm.put', 'm.entries' etc.

To get entries of your 'test' map, first you should change namespace to 'test' using 'ns' command. (Default namespace is 'default').

```
hazelcast[default] > ns test
namespace: test    
hazelcast[test] > m.entries
Total 0
```

You can see all commands with 'help';

```
help
```

Comment: Now i tried this.. IMap im = Hazelcast.getMap("test");
  im.put("key1", "value1");
  System.out.println("value for key1 is " +im.get("key1")); Now, i went to the command prompt and tried ns test, and m.entries, still i am seeing the Total : 0.

Comment: Make sure both nodes are joined to each other. Otherwise there will be two separate clusters.

Comment: Yes, both are in same cluster..   Members [2] {
 Member [10.50.26.189:5702] this
 Member [10.50.26.189:5701]
} --> this is from my eclipse and .... this is from my cmd prompt.. Members [2] {
        Member [10.50.26.189:5702]
        Member [10.50.26.189:5701] this
}

Comment: I am quite not sure, whether this(" Hazelcast.getMap("mymap") ") creates a map or not? Does it create a new one, or it expects for a map to be created already using the xml config?

Comment: It creates a new map and uses the default configuration. What do you get when yo do test>  m.get key1 ?

Comment: Is the process on eclipse in "running mode" or has it exited by the time you check the size?